# C++ MFC Naming threads so Procmon can see them

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, naming, visual-c++-6

Is it possible in MFC to give threads string names, so that other apps such as procmon, will dump out a more useful message, instead of just ThreadID #### exited, etc.

Also I'm using VC6 at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: I wish I didn't have to, but I must for now....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can by raising a special type of exception.  Illustrated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx).

Comment: But that only works if ProcMon is attached as a debugger so it can see the exception at the time it's raised. Otherwise, the application simply catches the exception and the naming information is discarded.

Comment: *If* ProcMon actually watches for that exception, then yes, with the condition that ProcMon needs to have been monitoring that process *before* the program named its threads.